# Changes in one branch appear in master

Tags: git

I´m new to git and I´m having this weird thing. I checkout to a branch, do some changes, then I checkout to master and the changes I made in the other branch are there. I´m not sure if I misunderstand the concept or I´m doing something wrong. The git version is 1.7.11-preview20120710 from msysgit.

This is a sequence of commands I made, I remove the file text.txt in mybranch, then in master the file is removed too.

```
db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (master) 
$ ls
AcNumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb  NumericSingleTextBox.vb

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (master)
$ touch text.txt

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (master)
$ git checkout -b mybranch
Switched to a new branch 'mybranch'

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (mybranch)
$ ls
AcNumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb  NumericSingleTextBox.vb  text.txt

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (mybranch)
$ rm text.txt

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (mybranch)
$ ls
AcNumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb  NumericSingleTextBox.vb

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (mybranch)
$ git checkout master
D       Controls/text.txt
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (master)
$ ls
AcNumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb  NumericSingleTextBox.vb
```

Text.txt is not in master anymore.

Edit for depot

I had the problem before creating that example text.txt. Now I renamed AcNumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb to NumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb in mybranch, and I can see the change in master:

```
db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (master)
$ ls
AcNumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb  NumericSingleTextBox.vb

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 7 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (master)
$ git checkout -b mybranch
Switched to a new branch 'mybranch'

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (mybranch)
$ ls
AcNumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb  NumericSingleTextBox.vb

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (mybranch)
$ mv AcNumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb NumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (mybranch)
$ ls
NumericSingleTextBox.vb  NumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (mybranch)
$ git checkout master
D       Controls/AcNumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 7 commits.

db@DB-PC /f/Projects/Controls (master)
$ ls
NumericSingleTextBox.vb  NumericSingleToolStripTextBox.vb
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, Git was never told to track text.txt.

Before you checkout of master, you must tell Git to track it.

```
$ git add text.txt
```

Once text.txt is staged, commit the addition to the branch.

```
$ git commit -m 'Added text.txt'
```

While on mybranch, tell Git that you want to remove text.txt. Associate that change with mybranch by committing the change.

```
$ git rm text.txt
$ git commit -m 'Removed text.txt'
```

After checking out to the master branch, Git will restore its state and text.txt.

Comment: Out of curiousity (I guess I could find this out myself), do you need to also commit the file or is just adding it enough? Also, I find it interesting that after switching back to master it output this line: `D       Controls/text.txt` as if it did something to the file. What is that? :)

Comment: Yes, the change needs to be committed. That output puzzles me, too!

Comment: I edited my question and added another example with files already tracked. It happens again.

Comment: Ok, I think I got the idea at last. You have to commit all your changes before changing the branch, else pandora´s box opens again! I don´t see the safety, I lost a file trying to manage this.

Comment: If you have uncommitted changes and you change a branch, git will try to bring those changes along to the new branch. Which means, the changes will be on your workarea, but not committed in the new branch. See `git status`. You can use `git reset --hard` to get rid of all workarea modifications.